# In linear regression, is it appropriate to have predictor variables that are discrete rating scores?

Tags: regression

Suppose I wanted to predict some continuous outcome (such as time spent) on a predictor variable that were rating scores, which range from 1 through 5. Would it be reasonable to regress

$$
Time = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Rating + \epsilon
$$

if $Time \in (0,\infty)$ and $Rating \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Comment: You should be fine as long as the assumptions of the OLS model are satisfied, such as normality of errors, no heteroscedasticity and so on. Can't say how your results might turn out in the end without any more information about variables or your research objective.

Comment: @Spur The key issue is an assumption you omitted: *linearity.*  The hope in this model is that the raw rating score is (approximately) linearly related to the outcome.  That can be tested by comparing the results to a model in which the rating is treated as categorical (thereby introducing three more parameters).  This is where your concerns about (approximate) normality of errors and homoscedasticity play a role, because it would be natural to use an $F$ test for this comparison when those assumptions hold.